# use polymorphism with go

Tags: go, oop, polymorphism

I'm trying to have a base class with some generic method and create an other class who inherit of the base's methods

```
package entity

import "fmt"

type Entity struct {
    Name      string
    Health    int
    DamagePts int
}

func NewEntity(name string, health int, damagePts int) Entity {
    entity := new(Entity)
    entity.Name = name
    entity.Health = health
    entity.DamagePts = damagePts
    return *entity
}

func (entity Entity) Attack(target *Entity) {
    target.TakeDamage(entity.DamagePts)
}

func (entity Entity) Defend(target *Entity) {
    target.TakeDamage(entity.DamagePts)
}

func (entity *Entity) TakeDamage(damage int) {
    entity.Health -= damage
    fmt.Println("Entity: ", entity.Name, " took ", damage, " damage")
    if entity.Health < 0 {
        entity.Health = 0
    }
}

func (entity *Entity) ShowHealth() int {
    return entity.Health
}

func (entity *Entity) Heal(health int) {
    entity.Health += health
    if entity.Health > 100 {
        entity.Health = 100
    }
}

func (entity Entity) IsDead() bool {
    return false
}

func (entity Entity) Speak() {
    fmt.Println("I am an entity")
}
```

The other class
package monster

```
import (
    e "magickombat/internal/pkg/Entity"
)

type EntityInterface interface {
    TakeDamage(damage int)
}

type Monster struct {
    EntityInterface
    e.Entity
    Level int
}

func New(name string, health int, damagePts int) Monster {
    monster := new(Monster)
    monster.Entity = e.NewEntity(name, health, damagePts)
    monster.Level = 1
    return *monster
}

func (monster Monster) Attack(target interface{}) {
    t := target.(e.Entity)
    t.TakeDamage(monster.DamagePts)
}

func Defend[T e.Entity](target T) {
    target.TakeDamage(45)
}
```

I try to use interfaces but I've an error

> internal/pkg/Entity/Monster/Monster.go:30:9: target.TakeDamage undefined (type T has no field or method TakeDamage)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Go has NO classes and NO inheritance. On top of the semantic errors that cause the build to fail your code has flawed design that is full of non-idiomatic Go code and that is obviously inspired by the *classical* OOP paradigm. Don't do that. Re-think and start over, just this time do it without inheritance in mind. https://go.dev/doc/faq#inheritance

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Trying to achieve inheritance wich is _impossible_ in Go (no matter how hard you try or how clever you are). Polymorphism is achieved via interfaces.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, there are multiple issues.

> internal/pkg/Entity/Monster/Monster.go:30:9: target.TakeDamage undefined (type T has no field or method TakeDamage)

Here the issue is you used struct `Entity` as type constraint, but type constraint should be an interface. Try this:

```
func Defend[T DamageTaker](target T) {
    target.TakeDamage(45)
}

type DamageTaker interface {
    TakeDamage(d int)
}
```

> I'm trying to have a base class with some generic method and create an other class who inherit of the base's methods

Go doesn't really provide the usual OOP inheritance.

However one achieve polymorphism with interfaces, see example below.

Play it on [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/6Ip9scm4c3).

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Talker interface {
        Talk(words string)
}

type Cat struct {
        name string
}

type Dog struct {
        name string
}

func (c *Cat) Talk(words string) {
        fmt.Printf("Cat " + c.name + " here: " + words + "\n")
}

func (d *Dog) Talk(words string) {
        fmt.Printf("Dog " + d.name + " here: " + words + "\n")
}

func main() {
        var t1, t2 Talker

        t1 = &Cat{"Kit"}
        t2 = &Dog{"Doug"}

        t1.Talk("meow")
        t2.Talk("woof")
}
```

Output:

```
Cat Kit here: meow
Dog Doug here: woof
```